# ¿Como puedo finalizar un script lua?

Tags: script, lua

Como puedo terminar mi script lua ya que al ejecutar da todo bien pero no se queda ejecutado solo se sale y da error
Utilise este proseso:

```cs
while(true)do
if gg.isVisible(true) then
XGCK=1
gg.setVisible(false)
end
gg.clearResults()
if XGCK==1 then
Main()
end
end
```

**O tengo que empezar todo de otra forma**

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar el Break, basicamente finaliza el while true do.

```lua
    repeticiones = 5 Cambia el numero por las veces que quieras que se repita.
    while(true)do
    if repeticiones <= 0 then
    break
    end
    if gg.isVisible(true) then
    XGCK=1
    gg.setVisible(false)
    end
    gg.clearResults()
    if XGCK==1 then
    Main()
   end
   repeticiones = repeticiones - 1
   end
```

Avísame si no funciona.